# How to show only last tweet of mine using PHP?

Tags: php, xhtml, twitter

How to show only last tweet of mine using PHP, without javascript?
I want to show my own last tweet on a web page.

in this output

```
<p>Add a comment to your closing DIV tag – it could save you hours 
   <a>http://ping.fm/venna</a>
   <span>8:25 AM Apr 15th</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would parse with php the result of `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?id=noradio&count=1` (replacing `noradio`) and then outputs the HTML you want

See also [this page](http://yoast.com/display-latest-tweet/) for some example

Comment: Ya, it has nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: @RC - ok i will try in evening

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: no javascript will be hurt during the test ;) It's pure PHP. In the linked page I added they use some php librairie to parse json but that's optionnal in PHP 5.2 (see `json_decode` in php manual)

Comment: @RC _ +1 Thanks for answer I will try then will tell you

Comment: @RC - Hi RC .I noticed this is for Wordpress. I need for simple PHP site. I'm noob in PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Here's another example: http://bit.ly/akUDpi (Note the PHP script is mangled by google translate)